# Stream bit rate in Android

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am developing Android application which use media player to view Live stream url. Application showing video correct. I need to know that, can we set stream bit rates programmatically? Please check screen shot which showing 1500 kbps at top left side of video and I need to set it 350 kbps.

[image: Image showing kbps value at top left corner]

Comment: Are you using a VideoView to play the video?

Comment: Yes, i am using video view and in on prepared method calling mp.start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using parsing m3u8 file and get bandwidth of that video.

Comment: How do you parse the m3u8 file. Can you please suggest how you do that ? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the bitrate using a VideoView. If you want to control the bitrate you will need to decode the audio and video manually using something like [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). You can then use [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) and [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) to play the audio and render the video at the desired bitrate.